# Spark 1.6 Facing Too Large Frame Error even after increasing shuflle partitions

Tags: apache-spark

I am facing this issue. I wasn't able to resolve too large frame error even after increasing shuflle partition.

Total records: 150 million

[image]

[image]

Comment: please specify the data Size and Spark executor memory configuration.

Comment: executor memory - 40G data size i do no because there are 5table join to make a another table..please tell me how to find data size

Comment: Hi Dassum, could you please tell how much memory we should keep to avoid this issue, shuffle partition i kept 900(tried by increasing upto 1800) is there any another way?

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you can try

1. Look in the log files on the failing nodes. You want to look for the text "Killing container". If you see the text "running beyond physical memory limits", increasing memoryOverhead should solve the problem
2. org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException can occur due to timeout retrieving shuffle partitions. try the below configurations

2.1. spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight=1;  -- Only pull one file at a time to use full network bandwidth.

2.2 spark.shuffle.io.retryWait=60s;  -- Increase the time to wait while retrieving shuffle partitions before retrying. Longer times are necessary for larger files.

2.3 spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries=10;

2.4 spark.network.timeout to a larger value like 800. The default 120 seconds will cause a lot of your executors to time out when under heavy load

Comment: Ya i am geeting 2nd error...i have already kept spark.network.timeout=100000...how much shuffle partition i have to give?

Comment: there is no fixed value that I can provide. These are the different configurations that you need to try.

Comment: Hi dassum My configuration command----> --spark-shell --driver-memory 30G --executor-memory 50G --num-executors=35 --executor-cores=6  --conf spark.port.maxRetries=10  --conf spark.network.timeout=10000000 --conf spark.executor.heartbeatInterval=250000 --conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=8192 --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=30000M --conf spark.buffer.pageSize=2M --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=800

Comment: try using spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight=1,spark.shuffle.io.retryWait=300s,spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries=10 also try to reduce the shuffle partition. Also please let us know the datasize and hardware configurations.

Comment: Hi Dassum the datasize - 375315464

Comment: Hi Dassum i have tried with above configuration  spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight=1,spark.shuffle.io.retryWait=300s,spark.shuffle.io.maxRetries=10 issue is coming again

Comment: Hi Dassum I have added the picture please look on that and let me know

Comment: why is spark.reducer.maxReqsInFlight set to 1? Is it per reducer?

Answer (score 0):

Error is saying that one of the shuffle blocks is too big to fetch. set `spark.maxRemoteBlockSizeFetchToMem < 2g`